# IOS UIView animation

Tags: iphone, ios

```
- (void)showLabelAnimation
{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animationID" context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

//original rectangle is (0,0,100,50)

//and I want to change label to (100,100,200,100)
label.bounds = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100);
label.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100);

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

It works well, but I just wondering why I have to set both bounds and frame of label. They seem like the same thing.
Can anyone explains this for me?
Thanks in advance.

[Edit in Nov 3rd]
Thanks for your help, but when I remove the setbounds line, it doesn't work well, the label will be large immediately but move to new position by animation. The resize animation does not show up.

That's the real thing which wonder me.

Comment: edited my answer to include more info regarding your edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only have to set the frame.  Bounds should update on its own.

Edit for additional help:
Labels don't scale; changing the frame of it changes where the text is placed, but the size of the text does not scale this way.

However, you can enable the UILabel's `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property to 'yes' and then before you run the animation, set the font size to be at its largest before running it.  As it scales, the font size should change to fit and achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it though I'm still confused.

Comment: For a simple explanation of how this works:  In a XIB file, make a label with a very large font size (like 80) and check the "Shrink text to fit" box.  Then, use the mouse to change the size of the box.  You'll see the text change size with the box.  The UIView animation you're using here is effectively equivalent to you resizing the box with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

The frame is the rectangle relative to the view's parent. The bounds is the rectangle relative to itself.

The animation should work without the line

```
label.bounds = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is working for me

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^(void) {
                     self.leLabel.frame = CGRectMake(labFrame.origin.x, 
                        labFrame.origin.y + 100.0f, labFrame.size.width + 50.0f, labFrame.size.height);
                 }];
```

For what you want to do, you should only set the frame.
If I change frame by bound in the previous code I will get a very strange behaviour.

So my guess is the reason you need to set both is because you've tested first with bound and added frame after to correct the error introduced by the setting of bound.

Comment: This code will only work on iOS 4.x and higher, where blocks are supported; though few users are still using 3.x, I still think it's worth mentioning (especially if this is the only place in your app where 3.x wouldn't be supported)

Comment: Good point. The other day I realize that my wife's iPod second gen. was running iOS 4.2. So I that time I decided to stop supporting less than 4.0 so I'm always forgetting to check that aspect.